# What kind of template for ios application

Tags: ios, xcode, templates, xcode-template

im trying to build an application like a book, with so many custom views and intensive animations. i want to know what is the best template for this kind of app? single view, view based?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a "Page Based Application" it comes with an interface that interacts just like a book with paging effects and everything. It uses one viewController that dynamically replaces content based on which page has been navigated to.

[image]

Comment: ok but that template is only for iso5 no? theras a way to make it work for iso4? the storyboard is the problem